MultiValueMap must not be null
I am upgrading my springBoot project to 2.7.18 and found the below issue while running unit test.
I am calling the blow code
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = mock(HttpHeaders.class);
Map<String, Object> req = new HashMap<>();
getHttpEntity(req, httpHeaders)

 private HttpEntity<Map<String, Object>> getHttpEntity(final Map<String, Object> req, final HttpHeaders httpHeaders) {
    return new HttpEntity<>(req, httpHeaders); // Here I am getting below exception but this piece of code was passing before upgrade
}

    MultiValueMap must not be null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MultiValueMap must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201)
    at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.<init>(HttpHeaders.java:442)
    at org.springframework.http.ReadOnlyHttpHeaders.<init>(ReadOnlyHttpHeaders.java:50)
    at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.readOnlyHttpHeaders(HttpHeaders.java:1819)
    at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.readOnlyHttpHeaders(HttpHeaders.java:1808)
    at org.springframework.http.HttpEntity.<init>(HttpEntity.java:102)

Any idea why it was started to failing after the upgrade and can you help to fix this?

Not sure why it's just now breaking, but if you look at the source repository that contains HttpHeaders and HttpEntity you can probably uncover the reason pretty quickly.  The fastest solution for you is not to mock HttpHeaders and just use a real instance.
